# How to Add device in IotHub in secure way?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-hub

Adding device in azure iot hub using below given code snippet

```
static RegistryManager registryManager;
static string connectionString = "{2131ueuruewejds342r2r2qq23udsjf}";

private static async Task AddDeviceAsync()
 {
     **string deviceId = "myFirstDevice"; // from where we get device id?**
     Device device;
     try
     {
         device = await registryManager.AddDeviceAsync(new Device(deviceId));
     }
     catch (DeviceAlreadyExistsException)
     {
         device = await registryManager.GetDeviceAsync(deviceId);
     }
     Console.WriteLine("Generated device key: {0}", device.Authentication.SymmetricKey.PrimaryKey);
 }
```

My question is , from where we will get the device id ?

Happy codeing

Answer (score 1):

The method you are using, is to create a new device in the IoT Hub. You can use any device id, like "myNewIoTHubDevice" or "AcceleratorDevice".

This method creates a new device with your device id and returns the primary key of your device. After that, you can use the device to send data to the IoT Hub, like the following code snippet:

```
private static async void SendDeviceToCloudMessagesAsync()
{
 double avgWindSpeed = 10;
 Random rand = new Random();

 while (true)
 {
     double currentWindSpeed = avgWindSpeed + rand.NextDouble() * 4 - 2;

     var telemetryDataPoint = new
     {
         deviceId = "myFirstDevice",
         windSpeed = currentWindSpeed
     };
     var messageString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(telemetryDataPoint);
     var message = new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messageString));

     await deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);
     Console.WriteLine("{0} > Sending message: {1}", DateTime.Now, messageString);

     await Task.Delay(1000);
 }
}
```

If you call this method and this method call was succeded, you can see the device in the Azure portal under your IoT Hub, under "Device Explorer".

This way is a secure way, to generate a new device.

Read [this description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-getstarted) to learn more about the IoT Hub.

I hope, I understand your question right.

Comment: Thanks Sean, I want to use SAS token or X.509 certificate to connect my device from IOT Hub. how to do?

Comment: ThanksSean,                                                                                                 I used device id myFirstDevice. How to configure my device which is IP enable with the device id myFirstDevice?

Comment: For using X.509 you should follow this steps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security#supported-x509-certificates.